# How to get the URL of multiple images in Firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

I'm storing multiple images at once in Firebase Storage and I need to get the URL of each one of them in the Firebase databse.

Here's the code:

```
private void SaveVersus() {

    comment = Comment.getText().toString();

    if (imageUri==null||imageUri2==null){
        Toast.makeText(this, "...Select a Image...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    else if(imageUri!=null&&imageUri2!=null&&imageUri3==null&&imageUri4==null) {
        //Save2ImagesFirebase();
        List<Uri> uri = Arrays.asList(imageUri,imageUri2);
        storeMultipleImages(uri);
    }
    else if(imageUri!=null&&imageUri2!=null&&imageUri3!=null&&imageUri4==null){
        //Save3ImagesFirebase();
        List<Uri> uri2 = Arrays.asList(imageUri,imageUri2,imageUri3);
        storeMultipleImages(uri2);
    }
    else if(imageUri!=null&&imageUri2!=null&&imageUri3!=null&&imageUri4!=null){
        //Save4ImagesFirebase();
        List<Uri> uri3 = Arrays.asList(imageUri,imageUri2,imageUri3,imageUri4);
        storeMultipleImages(uri3);
    }
}


public void storeImage(Uri imageUri) {
    StorageReference filepath = mStorage.child("Versus Images").child(imageUri.getLastPathSegment());
    filepath.putFile(imageUri).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot> task) {

            if (task.isSuccessful()){

                downloadURL = task.getResult().getUploadSessionUri().toString();

                Toast.makeText(ImageVersus.this, "Versus Published", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                GetInDB();

            }
            else{
                Toast.makeText(ImageVersus.this, "..Error..", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        }
    });

}

private void GetInDB() {

    mDatabase.child(current_userID).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            if(dataSnapshot.exists()){

                String username = dataSnapshot.child("Username").getValue().toString();
                HashMap InfoMap = new HashMap<>();
                InfoMap.put("username",username);
                InfoMap.put("imageUrl",downloadURL);
                versusDBRef.child(current_userID).updateChildren(InfoMap);
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });

}

public void storeMultipleImages(List<Uri> imageUris) {
    for (Uri uri : imageUris) {
        storeImage(uri);
    }


}
```

The problem is that, in the hashmap, I can only put the URL of one image and I need to get multiple URLs depending on what the amount of pictures the user select, if they chose two, then in the hashmap must be two URL's and so on.

Comment: every time it stores an image downloadURL is changed so you should add it to an ArrayList and then after your loop in storeMultipleImages you should call GetInDB instead of in StoreImage and then iterate through your arraylist and set the keys

Comment: @JRowan where should I put the Arraylist?

Comment: How do I add downloadURL to an Arraylist??